# MySQL Count does not fill variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Problem is:
I want to count the number in my column `r_start` where the `r_start` dates are between my other two variables. But it always gives me the Error Notice: `Undefined variable: z in [path] on line 173`. So it doesn't fill the variable, what makes me think that the `COUNT` does not work porperly. I did a lot of reasearch and tried some things, but I simply don't find the cause..

```
$sqld = "SELECT r_start, COUNT (*) FROM reservation WHERE r_start BETWEEN '".$cid."' and '".$cod."' GROUP BY r_start";
if ($result = $con->query($sqld)) {
    $z = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

This error only appears with the `COUNT` tag. In my other queries it works absolutly fine. 
f.e.:

```
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM reservation where r_ende between '".$cid."' and '".$cod."'";
if ($result = $con->query($sqlc)) {
    $y = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Can anybody tell my why? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL generally does not recognize a space between a function and the opening paren.  I would also advise that you give the column an alias:

```
SELECT r_start, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM reservation r
WHERE r_start BETWEEN '".$cid."' and '".$cod."'
GROUP BY r_start;
```

You should also learn to use parameters to pass values into queries.  Not using parameters makes the code subject to unexpected (and hard-to-debug) syntax errors, as well as making it vulnerable to SQL injection.